# How to add dependency inject(dev) in integration test

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm creating an api with dependency inject(the dependency is a service class). 
It's easy to do unitest. However it always fails in integration test.

**The error message** is

> sh.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object
>   available for injection at
>   SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=ConvertService,parent=ImportEltResource,qualifiers={},position=0,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,866909318)"

This is a rest api and it's called by the following code:

```
    Response response = ClientBuilder.newClient()
                                     .target(url)
                                     .request()
                                     .header("Authorization", this.authToken)
                                     .post(Entity.entity(body, APPLICATION_JSON));
```

How should I add the ConvertService injector here to avoid this error message?

step 1:
     Create ApplicationBinder by:

```
public class ApplicationBinder extends AbstractBinder {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(ConvertService.class).to(ConvertService.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should add the test case code that is failing, instead of adding random configurations.

Comment: Can you provide your test case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by the following steps:

step1:
override run() method with the following code:
`super.run(apiConfiguration, environment);
        environment.jersey().getResourceConfig()
                   .register(new ApplicationBinder());`

step2:
Inject ConvertService in the new created API;

step3:
create ApplicationBinder class:
`public class ApplicationBinder extends AbstractBinder {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(ConvertService.class).to(ConvertService.class);
    }
}`

Then it resolves the dependency injection issue.